# Conditionally reset row_number

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to count my rows grouped by an id and ordered by a time value like with `row_number() over(partition by id order by time)`. But I want to reset the row count when I encounter a special condition.

For example in the table below, when `event = 'y'` I would like to re-count from 1 for the same id.

```
id          time                      event      rank
----------- ------------------------- ---------- ----------
400         2016-07-09 11:31:30       y          1
400         2016-07-09 11:31:31       x          2
400         2016-07-09 11:31:37       x          3
400         2016-07-09 11:31:38       x          4
400         2016-07-09 11:31:42       y          1
400         2016-07-09 11:31:43       x          2
400         2016-07-09 11:31:44       x          3
400         2016-07-09 11:31:59       y          1
400         2016-07-09 11:32:43       x          2
400         2016-07-09 11:33:44       x          3
401         2016-07-09 10:31:30       y          1
401         2016-07-09 10:31:31       x          2
401         2016-07-09 10:37:37       x          3
401         2016-07-09 10:38:38       x          4
401         2016-07-09 11:05:42       y          1
401         2016-07-09 11:07:43       x          2
401         2016-07-09 11:31:44       x          3
```

I tried a lot of queries but nothing comes close to what I expect.

Can you help me on this please ?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34355381/creating-a-rank-that-resets-on-a-specific-value-of-a-column

Comment: Indeed it is, thanks. I didn't find this thread during my researches...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a rank that resets on a specific value of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34355381/creating-a-rank-that-resets-on-a-specific-value-of-a-column)

Comment: I had a similar question https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/214729/how-to-get-row-number-within-a-group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a conditional cumulative sum to further partition the rows by the `event` field:

```
with cte as (
  select id, time, event,
         sum(case when event = 'y' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by time) as group_id
    from tbl
)
select id, time, event,
       row_number() over (partition by id, group_id order by time) as rank
  from cte
```